# Why we can't declare variable as "var" for lazy initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, initialization

```
private var TodosAdapter by lazy{ TodosAdapter() }
```

This is my code and when i declare it like this, compiler throws an error that ***`var`*** should be changed to ***`val`***

I am wondering when we declare it as `val` doesn't it change the value of TodosAdapter afterwards? I mean normally we can't change the value of variable declared as ***`val`***. How this happens, can somebody explain what is working behind this

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful for you to include the compile error in your question.

Comment: @khelwood compiler error is already included "var should be changed to val".

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I expect the error message is probably a bit more detailed than that.

Comment: @khelwood No, it is not and message itself is quite obvious. What is not obvious, and compiler message cannot relay in single sentence, is why and that is the question.

Comment: Type 'Lazy<TodosAdapter>' has no method 'setValue(TodosFragment, KProperty<*>, TodosAdapter)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate for var (read-write property

Comment: Above is the full error, i read the documentation of delegated-properties as did not find answer to my question. I want to know why we can't declare it as "var"